# Helper is not working in HandlebarsJS template

Tags: handlebars.js

I am new in working with HandlebarsJS. I have an array like below.

[image]

I wrote a helper like below.

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper("show_data", (data, catalog_number, attr_name, index) => {
     if (
       data.CATALOG_NUMBER == catalog_number &&
       data.ATTRIBUTE_NAME == attr_name[index]
    ) {
       return data.VALUE;
    }
 });
```

My template is like below.

```
   <tbody>
        {{#each this.catalog_number}}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ this }}
                </td>               
                {{#each ../this.data }}
                    <td>
                        {{show_data this ../this ../../this.attr_name @index}}
                    </td>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
```

But I am not getting any output.

Comment: I have said it a few times now, but you need to state what you are trying to do. It looks like you are trying to do some complex filtering from within your template and this is not a good idea. You should reshape your data _before_ you pass it to your template so that your template logic contains only simple loops.

`data.ATTRIBUTE_NAME == attr_name[index]`: What are you expecting this result to be? `index` is the index of the `data` array, which is a separate array from `attr_name`; it would be pure coincidence if this were to evaluate to true.

Comment: Thanks @76484. Actually I am getting `data.ATTRIBUTE_NAME == attr_name[index]` result always false. But why ? How can I reshape my data before pass it to template so that your template logic contains only simple loops ? Have you any idea ?

Comment: Please share your desired result. I do not understand what you want each row in your table to look like.

Comment: Thanks @76484. My desired result is like this table.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/l52Vw.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for sharing your desired result, that makes it possible for me to help.

What you are trying to do with your helper is to take a Catalog Number and an Attribute Name and search through the entire `data` array for the item which has the matching Catalog Number and Attribute Name and return its `VALUE` property. You are doing this for each `catalog_number` times the length of `data` for a total count of loops approximately equal to `catalog_number.length * data.length * data.length`. This is a lot of unnecessary looping.

I would recommend creating an index data object and passing it to the template. The index would be of this shape:

```
{
  [CATALOG_NUMBER]: {
    [ATTRIBUTE_NAME]: VALUE
  }
}
```

This way, in your template you can loop through each `attr_name` for each `catalog_number` and do a single lookup on your index object to get the corresponding value.

First, we will create our index object using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```
// assuming our data array is referenced by a variable called `items`

const indexedItems = items.reduce((result, item) => {
  const catalogNumber = item.CATALOG_NUMBER;
  const attrName = item.ATTRIBUTE_NAME;
  const value = item.VALUE;

  if (!result[catalogNumber]) {
    result[catalogNumber] = {};
  }

  result[catalogNumber][attrName] = value;

  return result;
}, {});
```

We will pass `indexedItems` to our template as the value of `data`. Now we no longer need to write a custom helper. We can use the [built-in lookup helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup), but we will need to use it twice because we need to lookup by `attributeName` and `catalogNumber`. Our template becomes:

```
{{#each this.catalog_number as |catalogNumber|}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{catalogNumber}}</td>
    {{#each @root.attr_name as |attrName| }}
      <td>
        {{lookup (lookup @root.data catalogNumber) attrName}}
      </td>
    {{/each}}
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/4Lujrkyp/) for reference.

Notes:

`@root` is a [convenience variable](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#root) provided by Handlebars, just as `@index` is. It gives us a reference to the root context object rather than having to use a path like `../`. In my example code, `@root.attr_name` would be equivalent to `../attr_name` and `@root.data` to `../../data`.

`indexedItems` is intended to replace the array of objects at your `data` property of your root context object. I am not sure where you are constructing the object that you pass to your template function, but this is where you would create the `indexedItems` object and pass it to the template. Like:

```
{
  attr_name: [/* ... */],
  catalog_number: [/* ... */],
  data: indexedItems
}
```

Comment: Thanks @76484. Your solution is tough for me. What is @root here ?  Where should I place `indexedItems` code ? Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu: I have added some clarifying notes.

Comment: Thanks @76484. Your solution is not working.  Should I use any `Helper` ? I am passing object like this. const result = {
        attr_name: response.attr_name,
        catalog_number: response.catalog_number,
        data: indexedItems,
      };

Comment: I am getting this in console.log().  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrDLO.png

Comment: @abuabu: This is because I used `ATTR_NAME` instead of `ATTRIBUTE_NAME` in my reduce function - (this is a good lesson on why consistent naming is important). I have updated the code and the fiddle link.